# IFeatureDefinitionProvider for selecting features from SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net-core

Using the `FeatureManagement` feature in .NET Core 3.1, I am trying to write a custom database feature provider that will pull features and whether or not they are enabled from a SQL Server database. To do this, [the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-feature-flags-dotnet-core) says you need to implement the `IFeatureDefinitionProvider` interface.

You need to return a `FeatureDefinition` class which doesn't contain whether or not the feature is enabled but contains `IEnumerable<FeatureFilterConfiguration>`. There are no examples anywhere online as the feature is pretty new, and even looking at the Azure implementation (one of their two suggested implementations along with appsettings.json which will not work for this specific use case) is pretty confusing. The documentation for the [`FeatureDefinition` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.featuremanagement.featuredefinition?view=azure-dotnet-preview) and [EnabledFor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.featuremanagement.featuredefinition.enabledfor?view=azure-dotnet-preview#Microsoft_FeatureManagement_FeatureDefinition_EnabledFor) do not provide any useful information.

Does anyone know how to use `Microsoft.FeatureManagement` in .NET Core 3.1 to extract feature data from the database?

Comment: Have you looked at the source? https://github.com/microsoft/FeatureManagement-Dotnet/tree/main/examples

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/FeatureManagement-Dotnet#custom-feature-providers advices to implement a sevice of `IFeatureDefinitionProvider` type and register it before `.AddFeatureManagement()`.

Comment: Quite good example: https://github.com/microsoft/FeatureManagement-Dotnet/blob/d29b699d936a24613010d97fc58c883edfae2781/src/Microsoft.FeatureManagement/ConfigurationFeatureDefinitionProvider.cs. In your case, you will use EF Core DbContext to read features from database table in ReadFeatureDefinition method. Not sure if you have experience with EF Core.

Comment: @user2250152 I think this will do what I need, if you submit this as an answer I can accept it and award you the bounty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right, the examples and tutorials are unbelievably shallow, confusing and don't clarify any of the concepts. However I couldn't help but notice that the example suggested above only deals with configuration settings, JSON, etc. but it would be hard to use for your purpose, i.e., querying SQL Server and returning the state of the feature.  What you need is an example of how to implement the interface `IFeatureDefinitionProvider` and be able to query the SQL Server database in a flexible way.  This is the way I would do it and not necessarily using the Entity Framework, ADO.NET is enough:

```html
namespace FeatureDefinitionProviderDemo
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.FeatureManagement;

    public class FeatureDefinitionProvider : IFeatureDefinitionProvider
    {
        private const string FirstFeatureName = "FirstFeature";
        private const string SecondFeatureName = "SecondFeature";
        private const string ThirdFeatureName = "ThirdFeature";

        public Task<FeatureDefinition> GetFeatureDefinitionAsync(string featureName)
        {
            // YOU SUPPOSEDLY GO ASYNCHRONOUSLY TO THE DATABASE AND TAKE THE GIVEN FEATURE PROPERTIES
            // NOTE: part of the following is dummy
            var featureDefinition = featureName switch // NOTE: I'm using new C# switch expression here
            {
                // let's say the feature is boolean and it is enabled
                FirstFeatureName => CreateEnabledFeatureDefinition(featureName),

                // let's say the feature is boolean and it is disabled
                SecondFeatureName => CreateDisabledFeatureDefinition(featureName),

                // let's say this one is a 50% percentage
                ThirdFeatureName => CreatePercentageFeatureDefinition(featureName, 50),

                _ => throw new NotSupportedException("The requested feature is not supported.")
            };

            return Task.FromResult(featureDefinition);
        }

        public async IAsyncEnumerable<FeatureDefinition> GetAllFeatureDefinitionsAsync()
        {
            foreach (var featureDefinition in new[]
            {
                await GetFeatureDefinitionAsync(FirstFeatureName),
                await GetFeatureDefinitionAsync(SecondFeatureName),
                await GetFeatureDefinitionAsync(ThirdFeatureName),
            })
            {
                yield return featureDefinition;
            }
        }

        private FeatureDefinition CreateEnabledFeatureDefinition(string featureName)
        {
            // NOTE: adding a filter configuration without configurations means enabled
            return new FeatureDefinition
            {
                Name = featureName,
                EnabledFor = new[]
                {
                    new FeatureFilterConfiguration
                    {
                        Name = "AlwaysOn"
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        private FeatureDefinition CreateDisabledFeatureDefinition(string featureName)
        {
            // NOTE: don't add any filter configuration as by default it is disabled
            return new FeatureDefinition
            {
                Name = featureName
            };
        }

        private FeatureDefinition CreatePercentageFeatureDefinition(string featureName, double percentage)
        {
            // NOTE: this one is a bit more complicated and could be connected to a percentage SQL server setting
            return new FeatureDefinition
            {
                Name = featureName,
                EnabledFor = new[]
                {
                    new FeatureFilterConfiguration
                    {
                        Name = "Percentage",
                        Parameters = new DoubleConfiguration(percentage)
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

```html
namespace FeatureDefinitionProviderDemo
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;

    internal class DoubleConfiguration : IConfiguration
    {
        private readonly double _percentage;

        public DoubleConfiguration(double percentage)
        {
            _percentage = percentage;
        }

        public IEnumerable<IConfigurationSection> GetChildren()
        {
            // NOTE: no children
            return Enumerable.Empty<IConfigurationSection>();
        }

        public IChangeToken GetReloadToken()
        {
            // NOTE: this is not supported and not consumed either
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public IConfigurationSection GetSection(string key)
        {
            // NOTE: this is not supported and not consumed either
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public string this[string key]
        {
            get => _percentage.ToString("F"); // this produces the requested value

            // NOTE: this is not supported and not consumed either
            set => throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```